# Minha List não é atualizada corretamente com os dados do banco

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, primefaces

Tenho uma `dataTable` e um botão que seleciona o objeto em cada linha da `dataTable`. Quando clico nesse botão um `Dialog` é aberto com alguns dados e um botão Enviar, quando clico nesse enviar a linha selecionada é editada no banco. Até ai tudo funciona, porém minha lista que preenche a `dataTable` não é carregada com os dados certos, no banco de dados ta certo porem quando faço a consulta no sistema a lista sempre retorna o que já tinha antes (Não atualiza). O estranho é que só após uns 20 segundos e um <kbd>F5</kbd> é que essa lista é atualizada corretamente. Alguém pode ajudar?

HQL:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "SolicitacaoBD.listarPorUsuario", query = "SELECT solicitacoesBD FROM SolicitacoesBD solicitacoesBD WHERE solicitacoesBD.enviadoPor = :enviadoPor AND solicitacoesBD.status = 'Aguardando'")
```

Método listarPorUsuario que fica no DAO:

```
public List<SolicitacoesBD> listarPorUsuario(String enviadoPor) {
        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        List<SolicitacoesBD> lista = null;
        try {
            Query consulta = sessao
                    .getNamedQuery("SolicitacaoBD.listarPorUsuario");
            consulta.setString("enviadoPor", enviadoPor);
            lista = consulta.list();

        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            sessao.close();
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

E no meu Bean tenho o método que carrega a `dataTable`.

```
@PostConstruct
    public void carregarPesquisa() {
    list = new ArrayList<SolicitacoesBD>();
        System.err.println("Pesquisa Auditor");
        try {

            SolicitacoesDAO solicitacaoDAO = new SolicitacoesDAO();
            list = solicitacaoDAO.listarPorUsuario("Liberacao");

            //Essa lista nunca é atualizada de imediato mesmo o banco estando certo
            System.out.println("Lista Auditor:" +list);
            carregarEnviados();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao tentar listar as Auditorias");
        }
    }
```

Tenho outro método que carrega outra dataTable que fica na mesma tela, uma é pra dados recebidos e essa é para os dados enviados:

```
// mostra na tabela todos os dados enviados
    public void carregarEnviados() {
        try {
            SolicitacoesDAO solicitacaoDAO = new SolicitacoesDAO();
            listEnviados = solicitacaoDAO.listarEnviados("Auditor");

        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao tentar listar as Auditorias");
        }
    }
```

Método que edita a linha selecionada, esse método fica no Bean que controla o Dialog.

```
public void editar() {
        try {
            //Anexo de Arquivo
            solicitacoesBD.setCaminhoArquivo(destination + nomeArquivo);
            copyFile(nomeArquivo, input);
            solicitacoesBD.setNomeArquivo(nomeArquivo);
            System.out.println("Arquivo nomeeeeeee: "
                    + solicitacoesBD.getNomeArquivo());
            //Anexo de Arquivo

            SolicitacoesDAO solicitacaoDao = new SolicitacoesDAO();
            solicitacaoDao.editar(solicitacoesBD);

            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgInfo("Solicitação Enviada com Sucesso");

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao Enviar Solicitação!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: qual seu método que salva os dados da dialog pro banco?

Comment: vou editar a pergunta e colocar

Comment: pronto, coloquei um Sysout no meu DAO pra exibir os dados da lista também e mesmo assim a lista vem errada, eu olho no banco e está tudo ok porem a consulta retorna valores que não deveriam aparecer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que você não está forçando o recarregamento da `dataTable` após salvar no banco. No seu método de **Enviar** após ter feito o `Save` você precisa refazer o carregamento da sua `list`.

```
public void editar() {
    try {
        //Anexo de Arquivo
        solicitacoesBD.setCaminhoArquivo(destination + nomeArquivo);
        copyFile(nomeArquivo, input);
        solicitacoesBD.setNomeArquivo(nomeArquivo);
        System.out.println("Arquivo nomeeeeeee: "
                + solicitacoesBD.getNomeArquivo());
        //Anexo de Arquivo

        SolicitacoesDAO solicitacaoDao = new SolicitacoesDAO();
        solicitacaoDao.editar(solicitacoesBD);

        // Recupera seu outro bean e força o carregamento
        ELContext elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
        SeuBeanDaDataTable seuBeanDaDataTable = (SeuBeanDaDataTable) elContext.getELResolver().getValue(elContext, null, "SeuBeanDaDataTable");
        seuBeanDaDataTable.carregarPesquisa();

        FacesUtil.adicionarMsgInfo("Solicitação Enviada com Sucesso");

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao Enviar Solicitação!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

---

Caso estiver utilizando **@ViewScoped** e não for possível alterar para **@ConversationScoped**, você vai precisar colocar no *Request Scope* seu **MB**.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ControleAuditoriaLiberacaoBean implements Serializable {

    public String submit() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getRequestMap().put("controleAuditoriaLiberacao", this);
        return "valorAction";
    }    
}
```

E no seu **MB** do `Dialog`

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SeuOutroBean implements Serializable {

    private ControleAuditoriaLiberacaoBean controleAuditoriaLiberacao;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        controleAuditoriaLiberacao = (ControleAuditoriaLiberacaoBean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getRequestMap().get("controleAuditoriaLiberacao");
    }

}
```

E no seu `editar()` chame

```
controleAuditoriaLiberacao.carregarPesquisa();
```

Comment: Obrigado por ajudar